# sort the menu alphabetically in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

am trying to figure out if there's a to sort the items(buttons) inside the menu in alphabetical order by means of a function in the typescript file, please the following code which uses angular material.

```
<mat-menu #menu3="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['A']">A</button>
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['C']">C</button>
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['D']">D</button>
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['B']">B</button>  
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the menu items in an array, sort the array, then render it using `*ngFor` , smth similar to:

```
public menuItems: string[] = ["C", "B", "A"];
// use sort() to sort the array in ngOnInit() or wherever convenient
ngOnInit() {
   this.menuItems = this.menuItems.sort();
}
```

then in the template bind the soreted array to `*ngFor`

```
<mat-menu #menu3="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
   <button mat-menu-item
           *ngFor="let item of menuItems"
           [routerLink]="[item]">{{ item }} 
    </button> 
</mat-menu>
```

Check MDN for `sort()` docs [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for custom sorting, etc ...